# Accessing dictionary inside Python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested

I have a list which contains dictionaries like this:

```
json_obj = [[{'id': None},{'id': '5b98d01c0835f23f538cdcab'},{'id': '5b98d0440835f23f538cdcad'},{'id': '5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdcb9'}],[{'id': None},{'id': '5b98d01c0835f23f538cd'},{'id': '5b98d0440835f23f538cd'},{'id': '5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdc'}]]
```

I want it to store in list of lists like this:

```
y=[['None','5b98d01c0835f23f538cdcab','5b98d0440835f23f538cdcad','5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdcb9'],['None','5b98d01c0835f23f538cd','5b98d0440835f23f538cd','5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdc']]
```

For reading the id from the dictionary I tried

```
for d in json_obj:
    print(d['id'])
```

But I see this error with the above code:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: You don't have a list which contains dictionaries. You have a list that contains a list that contains dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You have a nested **list of lists**. It sometimes helps to observe this visibly, note the nested `[]` syntax:

```
json_obj = [[{'id': None}, {'id': 'abc'}, {'id': 'def'}, {'id': 'ghi'}],
            [{'id': None}, {'id': 'jkl'}, {'id': 'mno'}, {'id': 'pqr'}]]
```

Your syntax would works for single list:

```
json_obj = [{'id': None}, {'id': 'abc'}, {'id': 'def'}, {'id': 'ghi'},
            {'id': None}, {'id': 'jkl'}, {'id': 'mno'}, {'id': 'pqr'}]

for d in json_obj:
    print(d['id'])
```

For nested lists, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from the standard library:

```
json_obj = [[{'id': None}, {'id': 'abc'}, {'id': 'def'}, {'id': 'ghi'}],
            [{'id': None}, {'id': 'jkl'}, {'id': 'mno'}, {'id': 'pqr'}]]

from itertools import chain

for d in chain.from_iterable(json_obj):
    print(d['id'])
```

Or, without an import you can use a nested `for` loop:

```
for L in json_obj:
    for d in L:
        print(d['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested list comprehension.

```
json_obj = [[{'id': None},{'id': '5b98d01c0835f23f538cdcab'},{'id': '5b98d0440835f23f538cdcad'},{'id': '5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdcb9'}],[{'id': None},{'id': '5b98d01c0835f23f538cd'},{'id': '5b98d0440835f23f538cd'},{'id': '5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdc'}]]
print( [[j["id"] for j in i] for i in json_obj] )
```

or

```
for i in json_obj:
    for j in i:
        print(j["id"])
```

**Output:**

```
[[None, '5b98d01c0835f23f538cdcab', '5b98d0440835f23f538cdcad', '5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdcb9'], [None, '5b98d01c0835f23f538cd', '5b98d0440835f23f538cd', '5b98d0ce0835f23f538cdc']]
```

Comment: Thanks It works but can u Please tell me about my error:

Comment: You have a nested list. List of list of dictionaries.